# Set DEBUG to false

Tags: iphone, ios6, xcode4.6

I want to test the below lines of code :

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define VAR 10
#else
#define VAR 20
#endif
```

In `project->build settings->preprocessor macros` I had `DEBUG=1` and `NSLogging` the value of `VAR` logged `10`.
 Then I set `DEBUG=0` to check if it loggs `20`. But it logged `10` only.
How to set DEBUG value so that `else` condition in code is satisfied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aditya said, other library used in application may have defined `DEBUG` macro and hence even I remove it from `preprocessor macro` the condition `#ifdef DEBUG` is always satisfied. 
The solution is simple though. Just use different macro name such as `IS_DEBUG` instead of `DEBUG`. This solved my problem. It was a matter of just a macro name.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it easy:

```
#define DEBUG 1

#ifdef DEBUG
#define debug(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define debug(...)
#endif
```

When you summit to appstore, comment `#define DEBUG 1` :D

This is the way I used.

I dont know how to define something like you but it's great if it's possible!

Could you show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT be setting `DEBUG=0` to get the right result.
Just don't define `DEBUG` at all to get release behavior.

Remember, `#ifdef DEBUG` code checks if `DEBUG` is **defined** or not.
Alternatively, `#if DEBUG` code would get you the right result.

Comment: So deleting `DEBUG` will work with my code. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. I changed the answer to that too.

Comment: DEBUG is a very common macro. Some other code or the IDE environment may have it defined. That is the sad reality of using a common macro. Also, if you change #ifdef to #if, then your code would work.

Comment: Then, setting DEBUG=0 is not working. Can you put the value of DEBUG macro in an int variable and cout/printf it?